# Smoothscroll. Рефакторинг кода

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте!

Как можно объединить или уменьшить вот этот код:

```
$('a[href^="#section"]').bind('click.smoothscroll', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 100
    }, 500, function() {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});


$('.j-home-link').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#home').offset().top - 250
    }, 500);
});
```